# Make struct behave like std::tuple

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I've written some generic code which manages a list of tuples. Now I want to use that code, but instead of `std::tuple` I would like to use simple structs, so I can access the variables using names instead of indicies. Is there an easy way to make these structs behave like `std::tuple`, so I can use it with my generic code?

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    float y;

    // some code to enable tuple like behavior (e.g. std::get, std::tuple_size)
};
```

I've tried adding a `as_tuple` member function which returns all members using `std::tie`. This works but requires to call this member function at all places where I need the tuple behavior.

Comment: Let's take a step back... why are you making a struct wrap a tuple, when the point of tuple is to avoid doing exactly that?

Comment: @Neil the only difference between class and struct in C++ is the default visibility (private and public respectively) so saying "its a class not a struct" is a meaningless distinction

Comment: If you want to use `std::get` et al with your class, why don't you just specialize it for your class?

Comment: @UKMonkey Imho, tuples make sense when writing generic code, but I don't see people using them all over the place instead of structs with possibly many variables.

Comment: `but I don't see people using them all over the place instead of structs` maybe the better question then, would be why don't people just use tuples rather than structs?  (There are a modest collection of downsides to using tuples rather than structs!)

Comment: @UKMonkey type safety E.g. `struct Point { float x; float y; }` is a different type than `struct Interval { float begin; float end;}` but `std::tuple<float, float>` is the same type as `std::tuple<float, float>`. Plus you have a name for the type and names for members. Good luck figuring out the meaning of each member in `std::tuple<std::string, int, int, float, X, bool, bool, int, int, float>`

Comment: @bolov The consequences of the type safety is quite far reaching; for example overloads of `ostream <<` etc ... but it's off topic which is why I suggest to OP that it would make a more useful question to them than this one.

Comment: @bolov You're being very confusing.  If you believed otherwise, you'd think that the consequences of type safety is NOT far reaching, ie is NOT an important feature of c++... So I think you're trying to agree with me (that needless use of tuples is bad and typesafety is good) while mis-understanding what I'm saying.

Comment: @UKMonkey my apologies. I confused "far reaching" for "far fetched" so I misinterpreted your comment to mean type safety is not that important.

Comment: @bolov no no - having a 'toTuple' function is the thing that seems far fetched to me ;)

Answer (score 3):

The manual way:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    float y;
};


namespace std
{

    template <>
    class tuple_element<0, foo> {
        using type = int;
    };

    template <>
    class tuple_element<1, foo> {
        using type = float;
    };

    template <std::size_t I>
    tuple_element_t<I, foo>& get(foo&);

    template <>
    tuple_element_t<0, foo>& get(foo& f) { return f.x;}

    template <>
    tuple_element_t<1, foo>& get(foo& f) { return f.y; }

    template <std::size_t I>
    tuple_element_t<I, foo> get(const foo&);

    template <>
    tuple_element_t<0, foo> get(const foo& f) { return f.x;}

    template <>
    tuple_element_t<1, foo> get(const foo& f) { return f.y; }
}
```

An other way is to write functions `as_tuple`:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...>& as_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple) { return tuple; }

std::tuple<int&, float&> as_tuple(foo& f) { return std::tie(f.x, f.y); }
```

and wrap your call before using tuple-like.

Comment: I would be nice if your manual solution could somehow be generated, only needing to specify the order of member variables.

Comment: If  you write `as_tuple`, you may directly do `template <std::size_t I> tuple_element_t<I, foo>& get(foo&f) { return std::get<I>(as_tuple(f));}`

Answer (score 0):

First, `as_tuple` should be a free function in the namespace of the class.  This lets you extend types other people write.

Next, you should attempt to call `get` in an ADL-enabled context.

```
using std::get;
auto& x = get<1>(foo);
```

if you do that we can pull off some magic.

```
struct get_from_as_tuple {
  template<std::size_t I,
    class T,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of< get_from_as_tuple, std::decay_t<T> >, bool > = true
  >
  friend decltype(auto) get( T&& t ) {
    return std::get<I>( as_tuple( std::forward<T>(t) ) );
  }
};
```

now

```
struct foo:get_from_as_tuple {
  int x;
  float y;

  friend auto as_tuple( get_from_as_tuple const& self ) {
    return std::tie( self.x, self.y );
  }
};
```

we can do this:

```
foo f;
using std::get;
std::cout << get<0>(f) << "," << get<1>(f) << "\n";
```

Now, this still doesn't enable `tuple_size` and `tuple_element`.

There is no trivial way to do that part, but we can work around it.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

namespace tup {
  namespace adl_get {
    using std::get;
    template<std::size_t I,
      class T
    >
    auto get_helper( T&& t )
    RETURNS( get<I>(std::forward<T>(t) ) )
  }
  template<std::size_t I, class T>
  auto get( T&& t )
  RETURNS(adl_get::get_helper<I>(std::forward<T>(t)))
}
```

now `tup::get<7>( x )` will dispatch to either `std::get` or another `get` in `x`'s namespace based off of overload resolution rules.

We can create similar helpers:

```
namespace util {
  template<class T>
  struct tag_t {constexpr tag_t(){}};
  template<class T>
  constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
}
namespace tup {
  namespace adl_tuple_size {
    template<class T>
    constexpr std::size_t get_tuple_size( tag_t<T>, ... ) {
      return std::tuple_size<T>::value;
    }
    template<class T>
    constexpr auto get_tuple_size( tag_t<T>, int )
    RETURNS( tuple_size( tag_t<T> ) )
  }
  template<class T>
  constexpr std::size_t tuple_size() {
    return adl_tuple_size::get_tuple_size( tag<T> );
  }
}
```

now `tup::tuple_size<Foo>()` is a `constexpr` call that gets the size of `Foo` by either (A) invoking `tuple_size( tag_t<Foo> )` in an ADL-enabled context, or (B) returning `std::tuple_size<Foo>::value`.

Once we have this we can create another helper base type:

```
struct tuple_size_from_as_tuple {
  template<std::size_t I,
    class T,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of< get_from_as_tuple, std::decay_t<T> >, bool > = true
  >
 friend std::size_t tuple_size( T&& t ) {
    return std::tuple_size< decltype(as_tuple( std::forward<T>(t) ) ) >::value;
  }
};

struct as_tuple_helpers : get_from_as_tuple, tuple_size_from_as_tuple {};

struct foo:as_tuple_helpers {
  // ..
};
```

and we now have 2 primitives.

Repeat this for `tag_t<E&> tuple_element( tag_t<T> )`.  Then we can write a `tup::tuple_element<T, 0>` alias that dispatches as you like it.

Finally, adapt your existing code that works with `std::` tuple facilities to use `tup::` facilities.  It should work with existing `tuple` code, and will also work with types inherited from `as_tuple_helper` which has a `friend as_tuple` defined.

This does not, however, give you support for structured bindings.